# Removing an element from ArrayList while looping over it

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to loop over a array of brickEnemies and if  my condition is true then the brick should be removed from my array. I get the following error **IndexOutOfBoundsException**. How could I make my for loop keep going after i have removed an element?

```
    int lengthofBrickEnemies = brickEnemies.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthofBrickEnemies; i++) {
        Brick brick = brickEnemies.get(i);
        int newPosition_X = brick.getPositionX() - SPEED;
        if (newPosition_X > 0) {
            brick.setPositionX(newPosition_X);
        } else {
            brickEnemies.remove(i);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's not an Array, it's an ArrayList right?

Comment: Yes Marco its an ArrayList

Comment: you're changing the array while within the loop. that means it's shortening as your loop runs, and your `lengthofBrickEnemies` reflects the OLD size. e.g. an array of 100 elements, you remove 10, you'll still be looping up to 100, but there's only 90 elements in there now and you run off the end of the array.

Comment: Check my answer @Pierre I used the same code, but you did some mistakes in the condition and in modifying the index when removing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an `Array`, but an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

To remove an item from an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) while you are reading it you should use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and then [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) method.

Will be:

```
Iterator<Brick> it = brickEnemies.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Brick brick = it.next();
  int newPosition_X = brick.getPositionX() - SPEED;
  if (newPosition_X > 0) {
       brick.setPositionX(newPosition_X);
  } else {
       it.remove();
  }
}
```

[`it.remove();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) removes the item returned by [`.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) call.

[`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) is used to make sure there are more items to iterate in the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by
>   this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only
>   once per call to next(). The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if
>   the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in
>   progress in any way other than by calling this method.